# DHTMLX Visual Editor. How to use generated code

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm a bit new to web-programming. Using [DHTML 3.0 Visual Designer](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/visualDesigner/live/#) I created a small web-page with the following automatically generated code:

```
dhtmlx.image_path='./codebase/imgs/';

    var main_layout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, '1C');

    var a = main_layout.cells('a');
    a.setHeight('0');
    a.setWidth('0');
    a.hideHeader();
    a.fixSize(0,1);
    var toolbar_2 = a.attachToolbar();
    toolbar_2.setIconsPath('./codebase/imgs/');

    toolbar_2.loadXMLString('<toolbar><item type="button" text="" img="dhtmlxSuite/dhtmlxToolbar/codebase/imgs/dhxtoolbar_dhx_web/save.gif" imgdis="" title="Actualizar" /><item type="button" text="" img="dhtmlxSuite/dhtmlxToolbar/codebase/imgs/dhxtoolbar_dhx_web/text_document.gif" imgdis="" title="Editar" /><item type="button" text="" img="dhtmlxSuite/dhtmlxToolbar/codebase/imgs/dhxtoolbar_dhx_web/print.gif" imgdis="" title="Imprimir" /></toolbar>', function(){});

    var toolbar_1 = main_layout.attachToolbar();
    toolbar_1.setIconsPath('./codebase/imgs/');

    toolbar_1.loadXMLString('<toolbar><item type="button" text="N1" img="" /><item type="separator" /><item type="button" text="N2" /><item type="separator" /><item type="button" text="N3" img="" /><item type="separator" /><item type="button" text="N4" /><item type="separator" /><item type="button" text="N5" /></toolbar>', function(){});
```

I don't understand how to put this code into HTML page. I tried to surround this code with `<script>` tags, create `function doOnLoad()`, and then add `<body onload="doOnLoad()" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; overflow:hidden;">`. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the docs](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=visualdesigner%3adesigner_from_designer_to_app)

You need to

- place basic html tags
- include dhtmlx.js and dhtmlx.css
- place script block, and paste the code from designer